# How can I iterate through mySQL data and pass it to the Twilio Notify Passthrough API?

Tags: mysql, node.js, twilio

I'm attempting to send a little under 10,000 SMSs using a single API call through Twilio Notify's passthrough API.

I've successfully connected to my MySQL db containing the data, but I now need to pass it to the Passthrough API in order to successfully send the message.

Here's what I've got so far. I swapped my actual db with a dummy db with read only perms, so the credentials are correct. Feel free to query that db if you'd like.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
require('dotenv').load()

const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const notifyServiceSid = process.env.NOTIFY_SERVICE_SID;

const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "asa.haus",
  user: "uhrjvef2i9dnc",
  password: "StackOverflow",
  database: "dbf2jpy2zqwjn4"
});

var recipientList = []

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
   con.query("SELECT CellPhone FROM test_notify", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // console.log(result);
    Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
        var row = result[key];
        console.log(row.CellPhone)
        recipientList.push(row.CellPhone)
    })
  });
});

console.log(recipientList)

client.notify.services(notifyServiceSid)
  .notifications.create({
    toBinding: [
      JSON.stringify({
        binding_type: 'sms',
        address: recipientList,
      }),
    ],
    body: 'Hello'
  })
  .then(notification => console.log(notification.sid))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Twilio provided an example as to how to do this in Python, but not in Node.js. This is the example they provided:

```
import mysql.connector
# lets assume that your table is called:
# `table_with_phone_numbers` and that the column is called `number`

QUERY = "select number from table_with_phone_numbers;"

# connect to the mysql server
DB = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="username",
    password="passwd",
    database="database"
)

RECIPIENT_LIST = []

# get a cursor to execute our query
with DB.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(QUERY)
 
    # lets loop through all the rows and append the phone number
    # to our list RECIPIENT_LIST
    for row in cursor.fetchall():

        # per our sample QUERY, the server should be returning one column per row        
        number = row[0]
        RECIPIENT_LIST.append(number)
```

Thanks for any assistance. Sorry if my question is a little unclear. Obviously I'm a little on the amateur side.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think, from your code, your `recipientList` is an array of phone numbers. When using the passthrough API, you actually have to turn each phone number into a JSON stringified object that contains a `binding_type` and an `address`. So you can create your bindings like this:

```js
const bindings = recipientList.map(number => {
  return JSON.stringify({ binding_type: 'sms', address: number });
});
```

Then you can send the messages like:

```js
client.notify.services(notifyServiceSid)
  .notifications.create({
    toBinding: bindings,
    body: "hello"
  })
  .then(notification => console.log(notification.sid))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

You can read more about [bulk SMS messaging in Node.js in my blog post here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-bulk-sms-twilio-node-js-html).